# Sample from the Erlang distribution in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, probability, distribution

The [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) has two parameters: natural number *k* (shape parameter) and real number *lambda* (rate parameter). How can you take a random sample of size *n* from the Erlang distribution, using R without exotic packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick to this question is to note that [the Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) is a special case of [the Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). Sampling from the gamma distribution is implemented in the [*stats package*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html).

The following function returns a sample of size *n* from the Erlang(k, lambda) distribution in a standard R vector:

> `rgamma(n, shape=k, rate = lambda)`
>
> `n` is the size of the sample.
>
> `shape` is the parameter `k`.  This is the shape parameter of the Erlang distribution (for Erlang, this must be a natural number >=1).
>
> `rate` is the rate parameter for the Erlang distribution.